# php chat show all messages

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to create a chat, but I have no idea to show all messages. Any help will be appreciated.

here's my PHP Code:

```
    <?php        $user = $_SESSION['user_email'];
                if(isset($_GET['chatid']) !== $user){
                $chatuser = $_GET['chatid'];
             
                  $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM  message_from  WHERE message_from ='$chatuser' ";
                
                   
                $run_user3 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_user3)){
                  $user_from_name = $row['user_from_name'];
                  $user_to_name = $row['user_to_name'];
                  $message_from = $row['message_from'];
                  $message_to = $row['message_to'];
                  $user_from_email = $row['user_from_email'];
                  $user_to_email = $row['user_to_email'];
                  
                     echo "$user_from_name,
                          You: $message_to,
                          $user_from_name,
                         $message_from"
                  

              }
}
```

----Here's SQL -----
1   id Primary Key int(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

2   user_from_id int(11) NOT NULL,

3   user_to_id  int(11) NOT NULL,

4   user_from_name  varchar(255) utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,

5   user_to_name    varchar(255) utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,

6   message_from    varchar(255) utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,

7   message_to  varchar(255) utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,

8   user_from_email varchar(255) utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,

9   user_to_email   varchar(255) utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL

Comment: (Possible) side note: Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries. See ["How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) and ["How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: **Warning!!!** Your code is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), please use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) preferably with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Where is `$conn` set? Where is `$user` set?

Comment: fyi, [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Example to fetch the columns from the database. you can try.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "YOUR_DB_USERNAME";
$password = "YOUR_DB_PASSWORD";
$dbname = "YUOR_DB_NAME";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE message_from='Doe'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $user_from_name = $row['user_from_name'];
      $user_to_name = $row['user_to_name'];
      $message_from = $row['message_from'];
      $message_to = $row['message_to'];
      $user_from_email = $row['user_from_email'];
      $user_to_email = $row['user_to_email'];

      echo $user_from_name + ", " + $user_to_name ", " + $message_from +", "+ $message_to + ", "+ $user_from_email + ", " + $user_to_email;
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Please add your DB credentials properly and update your query properly
$sql = "SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE message_from='Doe'";

Comment: What do you mean by DB credentials exactly? Sorry, but english is not my main languege... Well, it shows with two zeros, that it found two entries, but it's not displaying the entries. I splitted up the tables, I now have a table ,,message_from" and table ,,,message_to"

Comment: I found the problem. It was because of the styling